# is there a GCC -W* option that would alert me when I'm providing wrong argument for va_list?

Tags: c++, gcc, printf, gcc-warning, variadic-functions

This example code compiles without errors on my system:

```
void myFunc1 (const char * str, ...) {
  va_list argptr;
  va_start(argptr, str);
  vprintf(str, argptr);
  va_end(argptr);
}
void myFunc2 (const char* str, ...) {
  va_list argptr;
  va_start(argptr, str);
  myFunc1(str, argptr);
  va_end(argptr);
}
int main() {
  myFunc2("test %s\n", "arbitrary text");
  return 0;
}
```

but the result is wrong: `test ░˘G`

are there any `-W*` kind of switches to prevent this code from compiling ?

Comment: @nos you're free to add that as an answer there, improving the already existing question.

Comment: @rubenvb is spot on. We don't need to have a new question just because you found a better answer to the old one.

Comment: @nos: how to do that, can you show me the correct way on my snippet ?

Comment: @rubenvb I'm not going to do that, as that question is a general purpose question, not about wrapping printf.

Comment: @nos you are making no sense. If it is a solution to this question, it's a solution to that question. The fact that thinks such a thing would only be useful for `printf` is irrelevant.

Comment: @rubenvb Not if you take the code into account, and the fact that gcc can only do printf format string checking for variable argument functions, and nothing else. (i.e. this code wraps the printf family of functions, with the proper annotations gcc has a solution to validate arguments to such wrapper functions.)